# PostgreSQL - How can I ensure that an ID is not present in other tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, postgis, data-modeling

I have four tables in postgreSQL as follows :

```
Table A            Table A_POINTS  Table A_LINES  TABLE A_POLYGONS
----------------- ---------------- -------------- ----------------
id / colum1 / ...  id/  the_geom   id / the_geom  id/ the_geom
```

I want to ensure that one element in table A is present just in one geometry table.

Can I do that by making id UNIQUE constraint across the geometry tables?
In this case how can I do this in postgreSQL?

### EDIT

Yes what I want is some kind of unique constraint for the three tables. Table A is related with a Point, Line or Polygon but just one at the same time.

```
Table A            Table A_POINTS  Table A_LINES  TABLE A_POLYGONS
----------------- ---------------- -------------- ----------------
id / colum1 / ...  id/  the_geom   id / the_geom  id/ the_geom
 1   blabla         1  09838082..  3    082982..  2    092809...
 2   bleble
 3   blibli
```

So it's possible to do that?

Comment: Wht do you have three geometry tables (with exactly the same definitions) ?

Comment: Because I connect those tables to Geoserver and if I  have all geometries in the same table and I don't constraint it's geometry type, Geoserver will fail to render diferent geometries in the same 'layer'. I could have all in the same table, but later in Geoserver I would have to do SQL Views to separate it by geometry.

Comment: Views are indeed the way to avoid duplicate id's. But I reckon you want to have column-level contraints on the three geometry-types, too.

Comment: See my edit. I can control that by using some server side code and queries to the database. But I think if this could be a more elegant solution if this would be possible. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: You may be looking for table inheritance:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html.

Comment: I didn't know about the existence of that. According to the documentation: A table in postgreSQL can inherits from one ore more tables. So if in my case I make Table A inherits from (A_POINTS, A_LINES, A_POLYGONS). This should work? I mean If a have a point geometry with id=1 and I try to insert a line with id=1 will fail? Is this like a virtual join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally get the result by triggering a function before insert in each geometry table to ensure that the identifier i'm going to insert is not present in other geometry tables.

### EDIT

FUNCTION

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_check_denuncias_lineas_otra_tabla()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM denuncias_puntos WHERE gid = NEW.gid)
   OR 
   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM denuncias_poligonos WHERE gid = NEW.gid)
   THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Report geometry should be only in one table of geometries';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

TRIGGER

```
CREATE TRIGGER lineas_check_otra_tabla
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON denuncias_lineas
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_check_denuncias_lineas_otra_tabla();
```